Why am I getting stuck to a Platform (AnimatableBody3D) with Jolt3D?
I'm using Jolt 3D Physics for Godot, and my FPS character controller occasionally gets stuck to a platform moving with an AnimatableBody3D. Sometimes I get stuck to it, sometimes not. The behaviour is very unstable. Is there a fix for it?
See a video of the problem here as well as the complete project source on GitHub.
The steps to replicate are:

Download some starter FPS controller template (doesn't matter what FPS template it is, it seems to be a Jolt 3D issue).

Create an AnimateableBody3D with collision and a box, and animate it to go forwards and backwards.

Download and activate Jolt 3D from the Asset Library.

Run the game and let the animated platform move you a few times - you will notice that often times you stick to it for some reason.



It looks like I found a fix, it seems to work well, at least for now.
Go to Project Settings -> Physics -> Jolt 3D -> Kinematics and increase the recovery amount to something like 75% or maybe slightly higher.
It fixed the issue for me, at least at the current stage.

